# Copying List Type to an Abstract List

Tags: java, abstract-class, type-conversion, abstract-data-type

I have two classes that inherit from a single abstract class. The two classes dictate which type of AbstractList to use, either and ArrayList or LinkedList.

```
public class ArrayListMergeSort extends MergeSortData
{
public ArrayListMergeSort()
   {
    super();
    data= new ArrayList<String>();
   }
}
```

I was wondering how I would be able to make a new temporary AbstractList in the abstract class based on which type of list data is?

Comment: It might make sense to use generics depending on what you're doing with this. Take a look at the [Java Generics Lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have an abstract method returning a `List` in the abstract class `MergeSortData` :

```
public abstract List<String> getNewList();
```

Then, you implement this method in each sub-class.

For example, in `ArrayListMergeSort` :

```
public List<String> getNewList() {
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Any method of the abstract class `MergeSortData` can then call `getNewList()` to obtain a new `List` of the correct implementation.

Comment: FGITW wins...just as I was typing this same answer ;-(

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> newList = data.getClass().newInstance();
```